# can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string after following Heroku's tutorial on how to upload directly to aws s3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get direct upload to work on Heroku using jquery fileupload but it shows the error in the title.

I  really think I did follow Heroku's [piece of documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) thoroughly.

The part where it writes to change the view generated by the scaffold from

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :avatar_url %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :avatar_url %>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :avatar_url %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar_url %>
</div>
```

confuses me since when generating the scaffold we wrote avatar_url:string and our view now wants a file. And since there is no mention on what to do in the controller's create action, I kept the one generated by the scaffold.
For the record here is my create action :

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

      respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Some important information may be lacking there or it is totally possible that I am too much of a beginner to understand implicitly suggested changes too...

Either way, I would highly appreciate more detail on what to do to get this direct upload tutorial to work.

Thanks again!
Dan

The full trace:

```
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:81:in `type_cast'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:261:in `type_cast'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:295:in `block in exec_query'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:294:in `map'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:294:in `exec_query'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:68:in `exec_insert'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:95:in `insert'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:503:in `_create_record'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:87:in `_create_record'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:483:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:433:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:433:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:256:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AKeLTFglP6aT0OFd6/Er6lITrhleJ/OZyj2FUAMcssU=",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"yuiuiu",
 "avatar_url"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff590ce2b00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141215-7051-1s9e6tq>,
 @original_filename="imagetest.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar_url]\"; filename=\"imagetest.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would recommend using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle image uploads with Rails.

The Heroku tutorial refers to a client implementation of file uploads, which I would imagine is not a core requirement of your application. The gems I mentioned use the server as a temporary cache, so you can specify `file_field` in your view and it will handle the database relationship via an AvatarUploader (or whatever kind of uploader you use).

You'll also need to configure [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) with one of those gems if you want to communicate with S3. I would recommend Carrierwave, its my favorite and their documentation spells out how to handle this with Rails.

Comment: Thank you Bobby Matson! I already managed to get both gems working, but I am still on the learning curve so I would rather not give up that track. On top of that, it seems to be more interesting this way since the charge on the server will be reduced.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have gathered other feedbacks and they say the same, about chosing Paperclip or Carrierwave.
However, as far as I know, this means that the files will get uploaded twice which doesn't seem to be the most efficient result.
Any thought on why in spite of this drawback, people seem to favor using these gems over a direct upload handled by Javascript?

Comment: how would the files get uploaded twice? If you are using S3, they should only get saved in that bucket once.

Comment: That is what is said in the beginning of the [tutorial I tried to complete](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails). It will be uploaded to s3 once, but it must be first uploaded to the heroku server as a temporary cache which will then stream it back to the s3 bucket.

Comment: I see, could you provide a reference to the article? It seems like there wouldn't too much of a performance hit

Comment: Sure, just click on the "tutorial I tried to complete", it has the link, or in the question's body "piece of documentation". :)